# Subset dataframe with keywords

Tags: r, dataframe, text, subset, keyword

I have a dataframe consisting of twitter data (ID number, follower_count, clean_text). I am interested in dividing my dataframe into two subsets: one where keywords are present, and one where keywords are *not* present.

For example, I have the keywords stored as a value:

```
KeyWords <- c("abandon*", "abuse*", "agitat*" ,"attack*", "bad", "brutal*",
                       "care", "caring", "cheat*", "compassion*", "cruel*", "damag*",
                       "damn*", "destroy*", "devil*", "devot*", "disgust*", "envy*",
                       "evil*", "faith*","fault*", "fight*", "forbid*", "good", "goodness",
                       "greed*", "gross*", "hate", "heaven*", "hell", "hero*", "honest*",
                       "honor*", "hurt*","ideal*", "immoral*", "kill*",  "liar*","loyal*",
                       "murder*", "offend*", "pain", "peace*","protest", "punish*","rebel*",
                       "respect", "revenge*", "ruin*", "safe*", "save", "secur*", "shame*",
                       "sin", "sinister", "sins", "slut*", "spite*", "steal*", "victim*",
                       "vile", "virtue*", "war", "warring", "wars", "whore*", "wicked*",
                       "wrong*", "benefit*", "harm*", "suffer*","value*") %>% paste0(collapse="|")
```

And I have made a subset (`Data2`) of my original dataframe (`Data1`) where `Data2` consists of only the observations in `Data1` where one or more of the keywords are present in the `clean_text` column. Like so:

```
Data2 <- Data1[with(Data1, grepl(paste0("\\b(?:",paste(KeyWords, collapse="|"),")\\b"), clean_text)),]
```

Now, I want to make `Data3` where only the observations in `Data1` where the keywords are *not present* in the `clean_text` column. **Is there a way to do the inverse of my keyword subsetting above? Or, can I substract my `Data2` from `Data1` to get my new subset, `Data3`?**

Comment: `Data3 <- Data1[!with(Data1, grepl(paste0("\\b(?:",paste(KeyWords, collapse="|"),")\\b"), clean_text)),]`? (note the "!" there - that just reverses any TRUE into FALSE and vice versa)

Comment: @Parfait it just didn't seem like that's enough for an actual answer, but if you say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "inverse" operator in R is `!` - this will flip TRUE to FALSE and vice versa. So, with your example, what you're looking for is

```
Data3 <- Data1[!with(Data1, grepl(paste0("\\b(?:",paste(KeyWords, collapse="|"),")\\b"), clean_text)),]
```